# Unknown apps Cannot be installed by this user In Android 14 Pixel 7a

Tags: android, android-14

When I try to install my application as APK. The pop-up shows

> Unknown apps can't be installed by this user

In android 14 pixel 7A. Is there any way to install the application via APK?

**So far tried solutions :**

- I allowed an unknown app installation in mobile settings
- I denied the playstore Google App Protection  Detection
- Tried using Test Dpc app in Playstore

but still facing issue.

[image]